# problem in use of $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

Values the database row `units` for values **salam** & **salavat** : [this values inserted by `json_encode()`]

salam:

> [{"name_units":"salam","price_units":"74,554","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman"]},{"name_units":"mokhles","price_units":"4,851,269","checkbox_units":["mobleman","tv"]},{"name_units":"fadat","price_units":"85,642","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman","tv"]}]

salavat:

> [{"name_units":"chaker","price_units":"5,452","checkbox_units":null},{"name_units":"khobe","price_units":"5,452,545","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman"]}]

In the example, do the following works:

**EXAMPLE:** [DEMO1- in here work my code](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign) & [DEMO2-in here just is for show all codes](http://jsfiddle.net/a6PWZ/)

**First**. please inserted value: **sala** in input => this have "tow" result, please clicked on each a of results: **salam** or **salavat** -> you see that get five output after click => **salam** & **mokhles** & **fadat** | **chaker** & **khobe**(In case must have three values, since we clicked on the word **salam** => **salam** & **mokhles** & **fadat**)

**second**. please inserted value: **salam** => this have one result, please clicked on result (**salam**) -> you see that get "three" output after click => **salam** & **mokhles** & **fadat**

I want in any case that is result search "five" or "three" value or "Etc.", get values `name_units` related with word that is click.

```
$('.auto_complete').keyup(function () {
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        //url: 'http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/auto_complete',
        url: 'auto_complete',
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var id_name = $('.list_autobox_hotel').attr('id');
            $('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
            if (data == 0) {
                $('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('<p><b>there is no</b></p>');
            } else {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('<p id="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</p>').appendTo('.list_autobox_hotel');
                });
                //////////////////////*HERE//////////////////////
                $('.list_autobox_hotel p').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var ac = $(this).attr('id');
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $.each(value.units, function (bu, key) {
                            alert(key.name_units);
                        });
                    });
                    $(this).remove();
                    return false;
                });
                //////////////////////HERE*//////////////////////

                $('body').click(function () {
                    $(".list_autobox_hotel p").hide().remove();
                    $('.auto_complete').val('');
                    $('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
                    $('.list_autobox_hotel').css('display', 'none');
                });

            }
        },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

for bin i done it as: (but this don't work and there is still the same problem)

```
$('.list_autobox_hotel p').bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ac = $(this).attr('id');
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $.each(value.units, function (bu, key) {
            alert(key.name_units);                
        });
    });
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
});
```

i don't understand `"filter the data depending on what item you click on"` and not know how is it!?

**UPDATE 2**

Did this is true? (but this don't work and there is alert: `undefined`)

```
$('.list_autobox_hotel p').bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ac = $(this).attr('id');
    var ok = $.grep(data, function (e) {
        return e.name == ac;
    }).units;
    alert(ok);
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your code doesn't care which item you click on, it always shows all the data anyway.

You should either bind the click event inside the loop where you add the items, so that you can use the specific data for each item, or filter the data depending on what item you click on.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand, then?

Comment: Using `.click(` and `.bind("click",` does the same thing, so naturally you see no change. The difference that I meant is *where* you bind the click event, not how. If you bind the event inside the loop that adds the items, you have the units for that item available as `value.units`. If you bind the click event as you do now, you would use `$.grep(data,function(e){return e.name==ac;}).units` to get the units for the clicked item.

Comment: Please check update 2. i'm really ashamed, please do your own changes in my code.

Comment: My mistake, the `grep` methods returns an array, so you need to put a `[0]` before `.units` to access the item in the array.

Comment: I change to `[0].units`, output `salam`[after click on it] is: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`... "Stackoverflow" does not allow will be updated first post , please read full description at the link: [description](http://jsfiddle.net/HZMP3/4/)

Comment: here is content database and json response and test of my code: http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign. how is get words `salam, mokhles, fadat` instead of => `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` -> after search word `salam` and click on it?

Comment: You do exactly like you did before, you loop through the array: `$.each(ok, function (bu, key) { alert(key.name_units); });`.

Comment: i want append tow input with each `key.name_units`, this is my code but don't worked true: `$.each(ok, function (bu, key) {$("<p/>").append(key.name_units ,$("<input/>",{type:"text", name:"a[]"}),$("<input/>",{type:"text", name:"a[]"})).appendTo(".list");});
` how is it!? [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HZMP3/6/)

Comment: The `append` method is for appending elements, but `key.name_units` is not an element, it's just plain text, so it won't work. You would use the `text` method to set the text of an element, which you could then append to the paragraph.

Comment: I can append `key.name_units` with tow input and it not problem. Please see you, did it is true? => [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/EL6WH/) & [Test](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

Comment: That's because the element doesn't exist when you try to bind the event on it.

Comment: why after search and click on result search and click on plus next to input "INSERT VALUE HERE"(button add input) in the example, in new input `$('.auto_complete').keyup(function () { ...` not work.

EXAMPLE: http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign

Comment: It's working once for one field, but as you have the same set of variables for both fields, it only works for one field, and only one time. You would have to bind the events separately and use a closure so that each element has its own set of variables, or change the logic so that you only use the value in the field and don't need any state variables.

Comment: Hello my friend,please help me. in the [demo](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign) i have three field with class `.eghamat`, i don't know why don't work(not have results search) autocomplete in tow field first and second(`INSERT VALUE HERE 1`, `INSERT VALUE HERE 2`) but in field third(`INSERT VALUE HERE 3`) worked (have results search).

What is your comment about (caused) this problem? what do i do?

**Demo:** [see demo of code](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)<br>
**See full code(HTML & JS):** http://jsfiddle.net/hCkE4/