# append two input with each $.each.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want append two inputs with each `key.name_units`. this is my code but don't worked true:

```
 $.each(ok, function (bu, key) {
     $("<p/>").append(key.name_units, $("<input/>", {
         type: "text",
         Name: "a[]"
     }), $("<input/>", {
         type: "text",
         name: "a[]"
     })).appendTo(".list");
 });
```

How is it!?

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SXXee/)**

Comment: You'll need to explain better what you're trying to do

Comment: I don't think the Selena speaks very good English, so try looking at the example fiddle.

Comment: Related question (somehow, I think): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291898/problem-in-use-of-each

Comment: @Felix Kling yes, it is Related question, see demo in here: http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the wrong selector to which data will be appended.

You've defined `<p/>`, but if you want to append to a paragraph (`<p>some text</p>`), you have to define just `p` as JQuery selector: `$("p").append()`.

You also doesn't have `<p>` tag in your HTML in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SXXee/).

I also think, that you pass wrong arguments.

Describe what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

To use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over an array or object, you need to use different signatures for the function input. So using `function(bu, key)` is not right*.

```
function(index, value) <<< Array
function(key, value) <<< Object
```

Below are two examples using your markup as an example. Note I added a little bit of width to the `UL` so I could show the indices and values.

```
var ok = [1,2,3];

$('.list li').remove();

$.each(ok, function(index, value){
    $('<li>"key.name_units ('+index+', '+value+')" '+
      '<input type="text" name="out[]">'+
      '<input type="text" name="out[]">'+
      '</li>').appendTo('.list');
});

ok = {
    four: '4',
    five: '5',
    six: '6'
};

$.each(ok, function(key, value){
    $('<li>"key.name_units ('+key+', '+value+')" '+
      '<input type="text" name="out[]">'+
      '<input type="text" name="out[]">'+
      '</li>').appendTo('.list');
});
```

Which will output:

```
<li>"key.name_units (0, 1)" <input name="out[]" type="text"><input name="out[]" type="text"></li>
<li>"key.name_units (1, 2)" <input name="out[]" type="text"><input name="out[]" type="text"></li>
<li>"key.name_units (2, 3)" <input name="out[]" type="text"><input name="out[]" type="text"></li>
<li>"key.name_units (four, 4)" <input name="out[]" type="text"><input name="out[]" type="text"></li>
<li>"key.name_units (five, 5)" <input name="out[]" type="text"><input name="out[]" type="text"></li>
<li>"key.name_units (six, 6)" <input name="out[]" type="text"><input name="out[]" type="text"></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/SXXee/1/

* At least, I don't think it is.